# how to handle optional condition / null in single statement of lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

working properly with if else but when writing ternary condition for trantype as above, it's taking hours during execution and as a result getting 502 bad gateway for endpoint url and deadlock in database during deletion/insertion as well.

looks like, missing something, the way i wrote lambda expression.

```
var deleteItems = _EFContext.DbTable.Where(so =>
  so.Identifier == ProviderIdentifier && 
  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tranType)
    ? so.TranType.ToLower() == tranType
    : true);

_EFContext.DbTable.RemoveRange(deleteItems);
_EFContext.DbTable.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Did you look at what SQL was generated for this?

Comment: `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tranType) || so.TranType.ToLower() == tranType)` could be a refactor to consider

Comment: For error 502 you must have a special character in the URI string.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references?force_isolation=true

Comment: So you want to delete all where the conditions don't match? Because that's what you are doing. Why don't you use the `if...else`? If you have a condition where you don't want to delete at all, you should always prepend this before you start deleting with condtions for each record.

Comment: thanks, actually tranType is something which may or may not contains value as it's optional as per dev requirement and we have to delete all matching only from DB, may be case 1 based on only identifier if trantype is null otherwise based on both(identifier and trantype condition) using linq/lambda preferably